# Backstage - How to consume environment variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yaml, backstage

The [Backstage documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/conf/writing#environment-variable-overrides) states that all environment variables must be "exposed" through the central configuration file, `app-config.yaml`.

However, the official documentation is not clear about the use of these variables, for example, in the `.ts` and `.tsx` files.

Could someone help, or exemplify with codes how this use is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a standard configuration API for both frontend and backend plugins or codes. An API reference can be found [here](https://backstage.io/docs/reference/config.config).

You can try something like:

```
import { Config } from '@backstage/config';

interface IBackendConfig {
  KEY_1: string;
  KEY_2: string;
  KEY_3: string;
}

const getBackendConfig = (config: Config): IBackendConfig => {
  return config.get<IBackendConfig>('backend.env');
}
```

In your `app-config.yaml`

```
backend:
env:
  KEY_1: "value1"
  KEY_2: "value2"
  KEY_3: "value3"
```

**Note**: Because of this syntax, configuration keys cannot contain dots.

Another option for accessing the `env` value is to create a sub-view of the configuration,

```
config.getConfig('backend').getString('env').
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I can help those who are faced with the same difficulty I faced.

If you are developing a new front-end plugin, for example, you will need to create a `configSchema.d.ts` file in which you indicate the settings/variables it needs to access:

```
export interface Config {
    exampleConfig: {
      /**
       * Base URL Example Service
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      baseUrl?: string;
      /**
       * Params at url in Example Service
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      getParamsUrl?: string;
      /**
       * Number of results that must be obtained
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      resultLimit?: number;
      /**
       * URL for PUT method
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      putUrl?: string;
      /**
       * Params for PUT method
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      putParamsUrl?: string;
      /**
       * Token Example Service
       * @visibility frontend
       */
      token?: string;
    };
```

In the file responsible for creating the API, for example, you import `ConfigApi` from the `@backstage/core-plugin-api` package.

Below is an example of how variables/configurations could be accessed:

```
import { ConfigApi } from "@backstage/core-plugin-api";

[...]

export class ExampleClient implements ExampleApi {
    private readonly backendBaseUrl: string;
    private readonly baseUrl: string;
    private readonly getParamsUrl: string;
    private readonly queryResult: number;
    private readonly putUrl: string;
    private readonly putParamsUrl: string;
    private readonly token: string;
    private readonly managementAPi: ManagementRDMClient

    constructor(options: { configApi: ConfigApi; fetchApi: FetchApi }
    ) {
        this.backendBaseUrl = options.configApi.getString('backend.baseUrl');
        this.baseUrl = options.configApi.getString('exampleConfig.baseUrl');
        this.getParamsUrl = options.configApi.getString('exampleConfig.getParamsUrl');
        this.queryResult = options.configApi.getNumber('exampleConfig.resultLimit');
        this.putUrl = options.configApi.getString('exampleConfig.putUrl');
        this.putParamsUrl = options.configApi.getString('exampleConfig.putParamsUrl');
        this.token = options.configApi.getString('exampleConfig.token');
      }

[...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question, ended up just using `process.env.ENV_VAR` in the typescript files and exporting environment variables before starting Backstage.

Comment: And how did you carry out this process in the Cloud environment (AWS, for example)?