# Retrieving variables from one file to another

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yaml, app-config, backstage

I am working with backstage to deploy an application. I have app configuration file, *app-config.yaml*, that has a variable `version` that I want to pass onto a typescript file, *Root.tsc*.

```
app:
  title: Backstage Example App
  baseUrl: http://localhost:3000
  version:
     $env:VERSION_NUMBER
backend:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:7007
  baseUrl: http://localhost:7007
organization:
  name: CNCF
proxy:
  /my/api:
    target: https://example.com/api/
    changeOrigin: true
    pathRewrite:
      ^/proxy/my/api/: /
```

I have tried display the variable in my Root.tsc file

```
<div className={classes.upperversion}> {process.env.version} </div>
```

but realized the variable is not displaying because maybe I haven't included any file. How could I use the variable from my app-config.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative - not so suitable is to use Jinja.
You create a template, and it is populated during the build process.

I even asked a similar question recently as per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831512/backstage-how-to-consume-environment-variables).